# Valor de celdas en tabla html

Tags: java, html

Tengo la siguiente función sin embargo solo obtiene los valores de la primera fila del cuerpo de la tabla:

```
function manipulaTabla(){
var valor=$('#tablaProductoUnidad tr').find('td').eq(1).html();
document.getElementById('prod_descrip').value=valor;
}
```

Como obtengo  los valores de las demás filas al hacer clic

Esta función la puse en el evento `onclic` del cuerpo de la tabla

Html:

```
<tbody id="tablaProductoUnidad" onclick="manipulaTabla()">
    <tr>
        <%
            ProductoUnidad prodUni=new ProductoUnidad();
                LinkedList<EntProductoUnidad> listaProdUni = prodUni.ListarProducto("", 0);
                for (int i=0;i<listaProdUni.size();i++)
                {
                    out.println("<tr >");
                    out.println("<td>" +listaProdUni.get(i).getProd_cod()+"</td>");
                    out.println("<td align="+"left"+">" +listaProdUni.get(i).getProd_nom()+"</td>");
                    out.println("<td align="+"left"+">" +listaProdUni.get(i).getUni_nombre()+"</td>");
                    out.println("<td align="+"left"+">"+listaProdUni.get(i).getPu_cantidad()+"</td>");
                    out.println("<td align="+"left"+">"+listaProdUni.get(i).getPu_minimo()+"</td>");
                    out.println("<td align="+"left"+">"+listaProdUni.get(i).getPu_maximo()+"</td>");
                    out.println("<td align="+"left"+">"+listaProdUni.get(i).getPu_costo()+"</td>");
                    out.println("<td align="+"left"+">"+listaProdUni.get(i).getPu_precionormal()+"</td>");
                    out.println("<td align="+"left"+">"+listaProdUni.get(i).getPu_precioespecial()+"</td>");
                    out.println("<td >" +"<button class=\"btn btn-primary\" id='"+"btnAct"+i+"' onclick='"+
                    "prodModi()'"+" value='"+listaProdUni.get(i).getProd_cod()
                    + "' data-toggle=\"tooltip\" title=\"Actualizar\">"
                            + "<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-pencil\"></span></button>"
                    + "<span > </span>"
                    + "<button class=\"btn btn-primary\"  data-toggle=\"tooltip\" title=\"Eliminar\">"
                            + "<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-remove\">"
                            + "</span></button>");
                    out.println("</tr>");
                }
        %>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Puedes agregar tu HTML ?

Comment: ya esta el html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacer lo siguiente

```
  $('#tablaProductoUnidad tr').click(function(){
        var tds = $(this).find('td');
        var array_valores =  Array();

        for(var i =  0; i < tds.length; i++){
            array_valores.push($(tds[i]).html());
        }

        $("#prod_descrip").val(array_valores.toString());
    });
```

Comment: Esta linea: 'array_valores.push(tds[i].html());' no ejecuta

Comment: Prueba colocando una consola dentro del for para saber que si esta entrando a éste y me dices o dime si te saca algún error

Comment: soy nuevo en esto lo que estaba haciendo es poniendo alert en cada linea y justo despues de eso ya no sale el alert

Comment: Ya vi mi error, tienes que reemplazar `array_valores.push(tds[i].html());` por `array_valores.push($(tds[i]).html());` ya te lo edité en la respuesta

Comment: gracias Camilo me sirvió, es justo lo que necesitaba

Comment: Si te funcionó marca por favor la respuesta como aceptada así la gente que lo vuelva a necesitar sabrá que es la adecuada. Saludos !

Answer (score 1):

con esto buscas todos los tr de tu tabla
$('#tablaProductoUnidad tr');

una vez que ya tienes todos tus tr, le asignas el evento .click

una vez que le agregar el evento, buscas todos los td del th seleccionado $(this)

y posteriormente recorres todos los td's

actualizo la función para que a la hora de dar click en el th, te envie la información de los td

```
$(function(){
    var valor=$('#tablaProductoUnidad tr');
    valor.click(function(){
        $.each($(this).find('td'), function(x,y){
           alert($(this).html());
        });
    });    
 });
```

ejemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/madaver1980/gqtf9b6q/

saludos!!!

la liga es la misma solo que tiene una actualización, da click Apply local draft version

Comment: En este caso quiero seleccionar una fila para luego pasar los valores de dicha fila, revise tu ejemplo pero recorre todo los td lo que yo deseo es solo de la fila en la que haga clic

Comment: te dejo el ejemplo que requieres https://jsfiddle.net/madaver1980/2vx2xcgy/